In Angular 17+, how to pass signal<number | undefined> to a child component input signal<number>?
Say I have two parent & child components respectively:
Parent Component:
@Component({
selector: 'app-parent',
template: `<app-child [id]="id()"></app-child>`, // this gives compilation error
standalone: true
})
export class ParentComponent {
  id = signal<number | undefined>;
}

Child component:
@Component({
selector: 'app-child',
standalone: true
})
export class ChildComponent {
  id = input.required<number>();
}

Since, child component does not accept undefined value, it gives below error:
Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

I tried wrapping the child element in @if (id() !== undefined) {}. But it still gives the same error because it is a signal and hence can give a different value at different point of time.

I tried creating @let variable and tried passing it to child component, but Angular does not allow temporary variables like these to be passed on.



You can leverage the new @let to get the necessary type narrowing
@let myId = id();

if(myId) {
   <app-child [id]="myId"></app-child>
}


The @let answer is best, but you can also use default values to get rid of this error.
You can also set the default value, to bypass the value of undefined using the or || operator.
<app-child [id]="id() || 0"></app-child>

Full Code:
import { Component, input, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `child - {{id()}}`,
  standalone: true,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  id = input.required<number>();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <app-child [id]="id() || 0"></app-child>
  `,
})
export class App {
  id = signal<number | undefined>(undefined);
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
